# can you add a property to an object with setState()

Tags: react-native, javascript-objects, setstate

I have the following callback function:

```js
 handleAddList(s) {

      let myItems = {};
      let keys = Object.keys(this.state.items);
      for (var key in keys) {         
         myItems[keys[key]] = this.state.items[keys[key]];
      }
      myItems[s]=[];

      this.setState({lists:[...this.state.lists,s],items:myItems},function(){
         console.log(this.state);
      });
   }
```

but I'm wondering if there's a way to just add `myItems[s]=[]` to `this.state.items` without having to copy the entire object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

e.g.

```js
handler() {
    let myItems = {};
    let keys = Object.keys(this.state.items);
    for (var key in keys) {         
        myItems[keys[key]] = this.state.items[keys[key]];
    }
    myItems[s]=[];

    this.state.items=myItems;
    this.forceUpdate();
}
```

If you just want to update `myItems`.

`setState` and `forceUpdate`:

```js
        setState<K extends keyof S>(
            state: ((prevState: Readonly<S>, props: Readonly<P>) => (Pick<S, K> | S | null)) | (Pick<S, K> | S | null),
            callback?: () => void
        ): void;

        forceUpdate(callback?: () => void): void;
```

Comment: Not so beautiful I think.

Comment: that doesn't seem to make any sense. I assume element in my case would be items but where is the reference to myItems[s]=[];????

Comment: @DCR Just append it into the dictionary.

Comment: @DCR Can this works? Mine works well... (I set a breakpoint to make sure it really updated the components.)

Comment: I'm just beginning to learn this.  can you be more specific or provide a reference? I don't understand how to use this.  I'm told you should only update state with setState

Comment: @DCR Actually `this.state` is a dictionary. `this.setState(sth)` will do something like `this.state=sth;` and update all the components related to this state.

Comment: If you want to add something like you want to convert `dict={key1: "content1"}` into `dict={key1: "content1",key2:"content2"}` you can simplely do `dict.key2="content2"`.

Comment: So we can just use the method upon and add an item to the dictionary and tell the component "Render the components you created manually now!". Everything should work fine.

Comment: I tried your last approach dict.key2="content2". with setState but it didn't work. it replaced the entire object

Comment: @DCR We don't need setState anymore.

Comment: when did that happen. The class said only update with setState

Comment: @DCR I've posted the original code of `setState` and `forceUpdate`. Take a look and you'll know it just check and set `this.state` and do the same thing as `forceUpdate`.

Comment: from react documentation:  In general, you should initialize state in the constructor, and then call setState when you want to change it. Also, your last bit is so far beyond me it just makes me more confused

Comment: @DCR [DOCS](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-does-setstate-do) You know what it did clearly, then you can do it in your way.